# Query to select a row from a column that matches "x but not y" where y is everything else thats not x

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm trying to write a query that will select rows that match only what I'm looking for. If the row has other stuff, then I don't want it. The column is a varchar field and the values in the column are a comma delimited string.

So here is the dilemma:
The table has a recipe column and an ingredients column. Like this:

```
Muffin | "salt"
Cake | "salt,pepper"
Pie | "salt,pepper,butter"
```

In my query I want to find all of the recipes that contain ANY COMBINATION of salt and/or pepper but nothing else.

If I write the query like this:

```
select recipe
from mytable
where ingredients like "%pepper%" and/or ingredients like "%salt%"
```

I want the Muffin and the Cake be returned but not the Pie (because it has additional ingredients that are not specifically listed in the search criteria). How do I write the exclusion?

I'm using SQL server 2008

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Either way, the real issue is that you are storing more than one value in a single column. It's a bad schema and will lead to lots of problems, this one included.

Comment: Why are delimiting your fields?!?!  You should have 3 tables..  `product` (which contains Cake and Pie -- `ingredients` (containing salt, pepper, butter) and `ingredients_to_product` that link nth ingerdiends to a product by ID

Comment: Putting the ingredients in a separate table presents other issues like when searching for "pepper" but not "pepperjelly". I still need a like statement and I still need to exclude fields that don't match.

Comment: *"searching for 'pepper' but not 'pepperjelly'"* is TRIVIAL if your schema were correct. `WHERE ingredient = 'Pepper'` done. Your schema is a recipe for disaster (pun intended).

Comment: So all combinations could be ingredients with: (1) just salt; (2) just pepper, or; (3) salt and pepper. Union 3 queries together. The last one will require a count statement too.

Comment: Isolated, I don't know how many ingredients I will have when the query is run.

Comment: I feel like I could union two select statements; on to find the correct rows, and then one to remove those rows with extra ingredients, but I don't know how to find the rows with extra ingredients.

Comment: It's not readily extensible but this solves the problem as posed: `where ingredients in ('salt', 'pepper', 'salt,pepper', 'pepper,salt')` If you need a more general solution then you should clarify.

Comment: Never, ever store your data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already received comments encouraging you to consider a different design for your schema and the rationale for this so I'll only focus on a suggestion for your schema here.

You may consider using [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to determine if the column of ingredients will be empty or whether this recipe has no other ingredients. The `LIKE` was used to determine whether the recipe had the desired ingredients.

#### Approach 1

```sql
SELECT 
    recipe,
    ingredients
FROM mytable
WHERE (
   CONCAT(',',ingredients,',') LIKE '%,salt,%' OR
   CONCAT(',',ingredients,',') LIKE '%,pepper,%'
) AND
   REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ingredients,'salt',','),'pepper',','),',','')=''
```

[View working demo online](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8bab9d7ef83e13635f80f81d8a232fc4)

#### Approach 2

Ingredients that are only desired are placed in a subquery and filtered using the left join. The having clause is then used to determine whether the list of ingredients only has these ingredients .

```sql
SELECT recipe
FROM (
    SELECT 
        recipe,
        ingredients,
        desired
    FROM 
        mytable m
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 'salt' as desired UNION ALL
        SELECT 'pepper'
    ) d ON CONCAT(',',ingredients,',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',d.desired,',%')
) t
GROUP BY
      recipe
HAVING
    LEN(
        MAX(
          REPLACE(ingredients,',','')
        )
    ) <= SUM(LEN(desired))
```

[View working demo online](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=cc60e917aab2ca204c65f50b67f07bc1)

Comment: So this works, but only if I specifically hard code the ingredients in the query. I want to be able to pass a list of ingredients to the query (different every time) and have it give me the recepies that match.

Comment: @John I've updated the answer with a second approach, which is more flexible. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: The second approach is better, but it still has the ingredients hard coded in it. The ingredients won't be the same every time.

Comment: Using Approach 1 and some string building in C# seems to do the trick. It may not be the most optimal of efficient solution, but it does solve the immediate problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You really should have 3 tables for this solution.  You are suffering from the [X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Your solution for example should look something like this:

**product**

| product_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Muffin |
| 2 | Cake |
| 3 | Pie |

**ingredient**

| ingredient_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Salt |
| 2 | Pepper |
| 3 | Butter |

**ingredient_to_product**

| product_id | ingredient_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

Then you can simply write your query based on your positive ingredient list and not worry about what they DON'T HAVE:  According to your original statement: *"in my query I want to find all of the recipes that contain ANY COMBINATION of salt and/or pepper but nothing else."*  That can be accomplished using the `IN` operator

```
SELECT a.name FROM product a
    LEFT JOIN ingredient_to_product b
    ON a.product_id = b.product_id

    LEFT JOIN ingredient c
    ON b.ingredient_id = c.ingredient_id
WHERE c.name IN ('salt','pepper');
```

And conversely you can **exclude** with `NOT IN` --

```
WHERE c.name IN ('salt','pepper') AND c.name NOT IN ('milk', 'butter');
```

OR to include `salt` and `pepper` -- But exclude every other possibility .. Use a nested SELECT to exclude everything BUT salt, and pepper

```
WHERE c.name IN ('salt','pepper') 
AND c.name NOT IN (
    SELECT c.name FROM product a
        LEFT JOIN ingredient_to_product b
        ON a.product_id = b.product_id

        LEFT JOIN ingredient c
        ON b.ingredient_id = c.ingredient_id
    WHERE c.name NOT IN ('salt','pepper')
    GROUP BY c.name
)
GROUP BY a.name;
```

Comment: This is on the right track, but OP doesn't want products that contain non-salt and non-pepper ingredients (but do include salt or pepper). Probably a good candidate of `minus` or `except` or whatever SQL Server 2008 uses.

Comment: Thanks Zak, But JNevill is correct in that the list of ingredients could be multiple, so I can't have a select for each one.

Comment: @John See my updated query .. You can use `IN` for salt and pepper, just salt, or just pepper ...  but nothing else.

Comment: @John there is enough with the additional `WHERE` statements I've added, to get you started on any  level of filtering using BASIC SQL and not having to tear down a delimited list.

Answer (score 0):

```
select recipe
from T cross apply string_split(ingredients, ',')
group by recipe
having count(case when value     in (<my list>) then 1 end) > 0
   and count(case when value not in (<my list>) then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: While this does *technically* solve OPs issue, it's bad practice and doesn't solve OP's **fundamental** [XY Issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) which is the *basis* for the current problem (and future problems)

Comment: @Zak I'm not encouraging comma-delimited lists and that's a battle I'm not interested in fighting. Past the one line that un-splits the string I am using a proper SQL approach.